# Java 11 for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: java, openjdk

This refers to [Phoenicis issue](https://github.com/PhoenicisOrg/phoenicis/issues/1737)

I need to install Java 11, so I run this command

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

But it installed Java 10 according to:

```
tomsk@tomsk-Ntb:/opt/Build/Phoenicis/phoenicis-dist/src/scripts$ java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

One of devs said in that issue thread that Ubuntu provide Java 11 as Java 10:

> the Java 11 package in Ubuntu does not provide Java 11 but Java 10

So how can I install true Java 11 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

I would like to install it using repo or ppa, not binary.

Comment: @Kulfy so it means that Java 11 is not released yet?